# Deps.json file not rebuild when reference library remove

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

Why is my deps.json file not being rebuilt after removing a reference library in MSBuild? Application runs into 'Missing reference Excel.dll' error even though the exe file is rebuilt successfully. What steps are required to trigger the regeneration of the deps.json file when a reference library is removed?"